# How can I add attribute to show in apache tiles in Spring?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-security, tiles

I have the following part in **singinsignup.jsp** file which is a permenant sidebar in the right of the site. I can get username by using `principle.username`. But I want to get the information like user's email. I'm doing it in controller by using model.addAttribute but how can I send value for a tile. So, question is how can I use `user.email` of authenticated user in side bar tile which has the same view if user authenticated?  Thanks.

**singinsingup.jsp file:**

```
<sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
        <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/serhat/${principal.}.jpg" align="middle" />

        <span><sec:authentication property="user.mail" /></span>

        <span><sec:authentication property="principal.username" /></span>
        <br />
        <s:url value="/static/j_spring_security_logout" var="logout_url" />
        <a href="${logout_url}">Logout</a>
        <sec:authorize url="/admin">
            <s:url value="/admin" var="admin_url" />
            <br />
            <a href="${admin_url}">Admin</a>
        </sec:authorize>
```

**views.xml which involves tiles definitons:**

```
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.1//EN"
"http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="template" template="/WEB-INF/views/main_template.jsp">
         <put-attribute name="top"
            value="/WEB-INF/views/tiles/spittleForm.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="side"
            value="/WEB-INF/views/tiles/signinsignup.jsp"  />
    </definition>

    <definition name="home" extends="template">
        <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="login" extends="template">
        <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="side"
            value="/WEB-INF/views/tiles/alreadyamember.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="admin" extends="template">
        <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/views/admin.jsp" />
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

---

**UPDATE**

I have added **spt** variable like this:

```
value="/WEB-INF/views/tiles/signinsignup.jsp" expression="${spt}"  />
```

To do that I created a variable in my HomeController I added the following lines. But now I can get email address only in the home page as expected. I want to do it ones and use it in tiles everywhere so that I do not need to add this part in all of the controllers.

```
    Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    if (principal == null)
        return "home";
    if (principal instanceof String)
        return "home";
    if (principal instanceof User) {
        String username = ((User) principal).getUsername();
        Spitter myspitter = spitterService.getSpitter(username);
        model.put("spt", myspitter);
    }
```

Comment: Can't you do: `<security:authentication property="principal.email">`?